# ¿Cómo mantener una variable con ceros a la izquierda en php 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo mi base de datos en `mysql` con un campo llamado:

```
numero int(7) zero fill
```

En `php` tengo la variable que recibe el dato, ej:

```
$numero = "0000001";
echo numero;
// muestra 0000001
```

Luego necesito `sumar 1` a mi variable `$numero` :

```
$numero_nuevo = $numero + 1 ;
echo $numero_nuevo;
// muestra 2
```

Lo que necesito es que se mantenga el formato de `$numero` y que muestre :

```
0000002
```

¿Alguien conoce algún método en `php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede agregar directamente porque PHP hace una conversión de STR a INT, lo cual elimina los ceros, y luego le agrega el número.

Tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
$numero_nuevo = str_pad(intval($numero) + 1, strlen($numero), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Referencia: [Adding numbers with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054538/adding-numbers-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: muy certero, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que usar la funcion `sprintf`, el `%` indica el formato, así:

```php
$numero = "0000001";
$largo = strlen($numero);
$numero_nuevo = sprintf("%'0.0{$largo}d\n", intval($numero) + 1);
echo $numero_nuevo;
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php